# Checking Voter's identity

Tags: support

How to see the identity for the voters who voted for a specific question or answer? I have tried clicking on vote count indicator but nothing happens...please help

Comment: I was the 1st upvoting your selinux question so that explains 5 of your 13 rep (now 20 it seems) >:D

Comment: very well thanx...you and oli are the very supportive  :D

Comment: @Rinzwind -talking about repo you are about 65k repo so why count mine I am not even at your toes...

Comment: Oh but yours is easier to disect >:D

Comment: Small things are easier to disect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. To users, voting is completely anonymous (unless a voter wishes to say how they voted).
This is by design to try to avoid tactical and revenge voting.

If you're getting *hammered* by downvotes by what you suspect is a single person, you can flag the questions in, err, question and the mods can take a look. We can't see exactly what people have voted for or against, but we can see general trends ("User A voted against User B 102 times", etc) and if something looks dodgy, we can take action.

Comment: This answered my unasked question "is the moderator election a secret ballot?" :)

Answer (score 1):

As Oli says, it will always be anonymous - for instance [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9196/1785960) anonymously down-voted question on anonymous downvoting.
Also, [serial-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) is flagged or detected by the system and can be [reversed](https://askubuntu.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

**Note:**
Clicking on the vote counter will only show how many upvotes/downvotes a question/answer has (only when you [have enough rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/established-user)) - for example for this question:

[image: 2 votes up one down]

**Edit:**

This may not be the case for favorite votes - see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/10132/who-favorited-me?UserId=178596....)